# Do I need to use volatile?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, java-memory-model

Consider the following code:

```
public class MyDataStructure {

    int size;
    final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public void update() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            // do coll stuff
            size++;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, `ReentrantLock` imposes an happens-before relationship so `size++` needs to affect the main memory and the cache (of other threads) with the new value. Hence, no need to use `volatile` for `size`. Also, for the same reason the method `size()` can simply return `size`.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I'm confident that `size++` is fine, but I'm not so sure about `return size`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, can you elaborate more about `return size`?

Comment: the `size()` method might use a value cached by the CPU which may be out of date.

Comment: @dan1st, if I add `synchronized` or  use that `lock` it will work right?

Comment: @dan1st, or adding setting size `volatile`

Comment: you would probably need to use the same lock for both `size()` and `update`. I _think_ that `volatile` should suffice as well.

Comment: Caches on modern CPUs are always coherent. The cache coherence protocol takes care of that e.g. MESI. Forcing to read/write to main memory would be extremely slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Other threads may see a stale (old) value of size.

When other threads execute `size()` there is nothing there instructing it to ensure it's not reading an old value, such as a locally cached value in another cpu cache etc. Also worth mentioning is hoisting by the jvm.

An example, if you have a loop calling `size()` in one thread, it may never exit if `update()` is not called in the loop (or size changed directly), and only called/changed from other threads.

```
while (size() == 0) {
   ...
}
```

The jit compiler, (at least the modern part what used to be called the c2/server compiler) could happily optimize away (hoist) the size variable checks as it sees that it never changes in the loop.

**Update about alternatives:**

`volatile` *could* be helpful *if* there is only one thread that will ever *write* to the variable size, including calling `update()`. Otherwise it wouldn't be protected as `size++` is both first reading and then updating (writing) the variable so two threads could still read a fresh copy "at the same time" with the same value and both add +1 but instead of +2 it could then be a total of +1.
Even if there is only one writer I would argue against it as this could change in the future, and is a fairly subtle thing to have in the code so a future developer (including self) would stand a great risk of missing this.

So one option could be to add lock to the `size()` function as well. Possibly nice with the extra features of locks, or even use readwrite locks that would allow many readers but only one writer etc. It's not as readable (well rather verbose) as the other alternatives. Possibly nice with the future virtual threads too *if* it was a costly operation (it isn't in this case though).

Another option is just the traditional simple way of adding `synchronized` to both methods, or a `synchronized (this) { ... }` block, that would beyond doubt provide guarantees about exclusion and memory visibility. Only real drawback: This implies using that object instance as the mutex/monitor so might not be granular enough if other unrelated variables might need protection as well or others having a references to this object using it. You could then add special monitor/mutex objects for each. Pattern, a field each:

```
private final Object sizeMutex = new Object();
```

... and synchronize on those `synchronized (sizeMutex) { ... }` when needed, but then it starts to be more and more verbose/complex but still fairly obvious and understandable. Biggest risk would be the possibility of introducing deadlock. Most likely not even needed to be that granular, but good to think about.

Simplest option in this particular case though is to use the `AtomicInteger` or related classes for other primitives or even entire objects as others recommend in the comments.

```
private final AtomicInteger size = new AtomicInteger();

size() {
   return size.get();
}

update() {
   size.incrementAndGet();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So is adding `synchronized` or `lock()` going to fix `size()`?

Comment: synchronized uses the implicit lock. You should use the same lock for the getter as you use for the update method. Either that or make the field volatile.

Comment: @NathanHughes, can I safely ignore the warning `Non-atomic operation on volatile field 'size' `?

Comment: that warning would be a problem without locking but you might want to look into `AtomicInteger` as an alternative.

Comment: @greenButMellow if you had for example both `synchronized void update()` and `synchronized int size()` you could remove your lock and be safe. The danger of allowing reads of volatile / atomic `size` is that code can potentially try to access an element that is no longer there because there's no way to ensure you can get `data[data.size() - 1]` for example. With synchronized you can wrap that access in `synchronized(data) {}` and get proper guarantees

Comment: @greenButMellow: using AtomicInteger is a good suggestion, often that's a better solution than volatile.

Comment: I know this post is a year old, but @Mattias I am pretty sure you are wrong when you say: _so two threads could still read a fresh copy "at the same time" with the same value and both add +1 but instead of +2 it could then be a total of +1_.

Assuming the value is incremented using the `update` method it's not possible to have a race condition between multiple threads since the method locks.

If `size` is volatile the samentics are the same as if the `size()` method was also locked.

Comment: @leonov that was in the context of using volatile as a solution by itself instead of the locks

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I understand, ReentrantLock imposes an happens-before relationship...

Yes. When some thread W (W for "writer") unlocks a lock, that "happens before" some other thread R (for "reader") subsequently locks *the same lock.*

In order to take advantage of that relationship, you have to lock the same lock in both methods:

```java
public class MyDataStructure {

    int size;
    final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public void update() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            size++;         // happens before unlock() because things that happen
                            //  in one thread all happen in _program order._
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();  // Happens before a pending lock.lock() call in some
                            //  other thread.
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        lock.lock();        // Happens before return size because...
                            //  ...program order.
        try {
            return size;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct, but the **Update about alternatives** section is wrong. Maybe it was added after the answer was accepted.

In the scenario described by the OP, the semantics of volatile are the same as if the `size()` method was using the same lock as the `update()` method, or if they were both synchronized.

1. Regardless of anything else, there cannot be any race condition when calling `update()` no matter how many threads call it. This is the whole point of having a lock. So it's not possible for two threads to call `update()` and have the value only incremented by 1. The lock ensures a `Happens-Before` relationship for any fields inside it.
2. What `volatile` means in plain language is *every thread will always see the most recent value* of `size`. Which, in this case, is exactly the same as locking in the `size()` method or having both methods use `synchronized`.
3. There seems to be confusion about what a *compound operation* is. It is absolute true that multiple threads calling `size()` and `update()` may see the same value multiple times. This is because `size()` and `update()` are independent operations and there is no guarantee as to the order in which they are called.

   Any algorithm which depends on both of these methods for correctness (e.g. `if(size() < 3) update()`) is using them as a *compound operation*. Which means the code must be synchronized externally.